# Can I distinguish between dependencies that force a target to be rebuilt, and those that simply allow it?

Tags: build, makefile

Are there any build systems that allow us to create different "levels" of dependencies? Let's call them "required" and "optional" (although I know some systems have a special meaning for "optional dependency"). The idea is to allow something between a normal incremental rebuild and a full rebuild.

A "required" dependency is just a normal makefile dependency. If the dependency's timestamp is changed, the target is rebuilt. If you type "make" and nothing's out of date, nothing happens.

An "optional" dependency would say that the inputs to some target had changed and *could* stand to be recompiled, but the target is not actually invalid.

For example, let's say I'm running profile-guided optimizations (PGO) on a bunch of DLLs. Technically, any change to any part of the code *could* invalidate the profile results, and therefore I *might* want to re-run PGO. However, the program would run perfectly correctly if I did not do this, as long as all the hard dependencies had been updated. This might be nice, because PGO could take a while to run.

Of course, today I can solve this problem by excluding PGO from the "all" target, and manually calling "make PGO" if I want to run it. Or, I could simply omit most of dependencies for the PGO target to ensure it only gets built after a "make clean." However, this is manual work can't easily be generalized.

What I'd *like* to do is to be able to say something like "make " to rebuild only those targets whose *required* dependencies were out of date, and "make -optional "  to rebuild any targets whose optional (or required, obviously) dependencies are out of date.

Does any build system or neat makefile trick support this kind of behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it yourself, if you want.  If you add `OPTIONAL=true` to your command line:

```
make OPTIONAL=true
```

then in the makefile you can test `OPTIONAL` and add prerequisites to the target if that variable is set, or not add them if it's not.

There's no version of make (at least) that I'm aware of that makes this kind of thing available via a command line option.